# XNA C# Creating HUD in 3D

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, xna-4.0, hud

I would like to create a simple label on 3D display. Something like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4e/XNA_Text_HUD_Component.png/220px-XNA_Text_HUD_Component.png).

I tried using SpriteBatch and SpriteFont which only gave me more problems.
Also, I was through some tutorials that didn't help me.

Do you have any tutorials for me or any solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: My models were messed up, and it looked like one of them was used for a 2D display (didn't have anything to do with the 3D world). I was really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally split my 3D drawing code and UI code into two SpriteBatch's.. that way, I can apply one matrix to the 3D view, and a different matrix to the 2D screen overlay.

Comment: Great. Thank you! SOLUTION: Added another spriteBatch in LoadContent(). Then in the Draw() I used spriteBatch.DrawString()